# Trying to find out the best possible network setup to allow IPSec tunneling between networks through Cisco router and DreyTek network device

Tags: networking, router, ipsec, cisco-router

I'm trying to find out the best possible network setup for my test SOHO network.

My goal is to create a create IPSec tunnel between my network (`192.168.68.0/24`) and a remote network. The main reason I am trying to implement this configuration is that DreyTek is not playing nice with the remote network's Cisco Router.

Currently, the Setup looks somewhat like this

> ISP > DSL > DreyTek (Configured as Modem and Router with DHCP for LAN) > TP Link 16-port Switch > Lan (Lan1: `192.168.1.0/24` and Lan2: `192.168.68.0/24`)

I want to hook up a Cisco Router (867VAE-K9) or ASA (5510) in between the setup so that I could configure IPSec tunnel between my network (`192.168.68.0/24`) and a remote network (`192.168.67.0/24`).

#### So my first attempt would be to do a setup like this:

> ISP > DSL > DreyTek (Configured as Modem Bridge mode) > Cisco Router (867VAE-K9) with DHCP > TP Link 16-port Switch > Lan (Lan1: `192.168.1.0/24` and Lan2: `192.168.68.0/24`)

Is this the best possible way to achieve IPsec tunnel with the remote network?